# How to divide attribute table in map composer between 2 or more pages?

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, table

Does anyone know how to divide attribute table between 2 or more pages? In exported PDF it's unfortunately clipped.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

QGIS 2.6 (scheduled to be released in a month) has built in support for this. Tables can be split across multiple frames, which can be placed on separate pages or in different positions on a single page. You can also control how headers are placed on subsequent frames.

The feature can be found (QGIS 2.18) in Print composer, attribute table created and selected, `Frame > Resize mode: Extend to next page`.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a function for dividing an attribute table between pages, but you can make a workaround with SQL filters in QGIS 2.4.

1. Add a new attribute table with the same layer for every page you have.
2. Check the "Filter with" dialogue box and write an SQL expression to set up an interwal with the `$id` variable. In the examples below, 51 rows fill a page.

[image: First page SQL expression]

[image: Second page SQL expression]

The disadvantage of this method is that you can't disable the header, so the first row of every page will be that.

If this is a problem for you, then @Joseph's solution will be the best.

Comment: Oh and sorry, I made a mistake, the proper expression in the second table is `$id >= 51 AND $id < 102`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can, I tried doing it in QGIS 2.2 but get the same result as you.

An alternative is to export your attribute table into a csv format, open it in Excel and save it as PDF. The table will be more correctly aligned instead of simply clipped as it is in Composer. Which is also great if you want to make printouts.